# Sanitizer - Spring Boot CSRF token validation Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, xss, csrf

I have implemented Spring Securitym oAuth2 to my Spring Boot Application.

I did Vulnerability test of my application and i find out a XSS attack vulnerability at `https://myapp:post/login?_csrf=`

Attack sample is follow

Attack request : `https://myapp:post/login?_csrf=<script>alert('hello!');</script>`

Server Response :

```
{
"timestamp": 1530781641320,
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Invalid CSRF Token '<script>alert('hello!');</script>' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.",
"path": "/login"
}
```

this response `<script>alert('hello!');</script>` should be like this `&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;hello!&#39;);&lt;/script&gt;`

i want to senitize `_csrf` parameter `<script>alert('hello!');</script>` and i cant figure out how to do this. is there any filter to grab csrf error responce and senitize the response?

This is my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthWebFormConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
}

@Configuration
@Order(-20)
protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(cookieCsrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .xssProtection().xssProtectionEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(customAuthenticationManager);
    }

    private CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();
        csrfTokenRepository.setCookieHttpOnly(true);
        return csrfTokenRepository;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should use @ControllerAdvice.   https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes